# FizzBuzz only prints numbers divisible by three

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am learning JavaScript, and an exercise that I am doing...I don't seem to "get" it.

The objective to write a program using console.log that prints all numbers from 1 to 100, with exceptions.

The program should print "FizzBuzz" if the number is divisible by 3 and 5.

The program should print "Fizz" only if the number is divisible by 3.

The program should print "Buzz" only if the number is divisible by 5.

If these exceptions do not apply to the numbers from 1 to 100, the number on its own should be printed.

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0)
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Of course, this code does not work.

The numbers that do not apply to the exceptions do not print. Numbers from 1 to 100 do not print.

Any help explaining why...I would be very thankful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt doesn't work, since it only logs those values to the console that are `i%3 === 0`, since the first `if` has to be true before the second block is entered.

You can see this if you log the numbers that get printed:

```js
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) // only if this returns "true" the next block will execute
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
      console.log("FizzBuzz " + i)
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      console.log("Fizz " + i)
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      console.log("Buzz " + i)
    } else {
      console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Combine the first two if statements and it works!

```js
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz")
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps one should show with indentation that the second if statement, including all the else `if`,  becomes the one statement when the first `if` is true?

Comment: You are totally right, @Sylwester one should have done that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the first two if statements with `&&` (a boolean operator that means "and". For it to become true, both of the statements must be true. If one of them is false, it becomes false).

JSFiddle (open the console to see it working): http://jsfiddle.net/7236jnx4/

You can not just have this code:

```
if(i%3==0)
if(i%5==0){
 console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
```

Only numbers that are divisible by 3 will be checked by the other `if` statements. The first two `if` statements need to be combined together for it to work:

```
if(i%5==0&&i%3==0){
 console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
```

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 0&&i%3==0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    console.log("Buzz")
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```